# Cannot pass null value from asp:ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, objectdatasource

Given below is I am trying to pass date time value from a texbox.it passes all other values fine but it passes null values as  {1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}.I want it to pass null value.Please help?

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="Schedules" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetScheduleByDate"
        TypeName="WebUI.Code" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" ControlID="TextBoxSchedules" Name="ScheduleDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime"/>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) is a struct and in that sense not nullable, just like an int or a long. maybe `Nullable<DateTime>` will work.

Comment: Another option is `DateTime? myDatetime`

Comment: Thanks! i know about this concept but i haven't been doing everything correct. Now i tried again and it works! thanks guys!

Comment: @rene You should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by following code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="MyDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetSomething" TypeName="MyNamespace.MyAdapterType">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Object" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="enabled" Type="Object" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="True" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Method's signature

```
public class MyAdapterType
{
    public IEnumerable<CollectorPlugin> GetCollectorPlugin(Guid? id = null, bool? enabled = null)
    {
        //in debug mode i have here 2 null objects
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```